# Grabbing a Specific Part of the Previous / Next Nodes

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml

I am looping through a XML file with SimpleXML and trying to pull a specific piece of data (specifically, the ***series->displayname*** attribute) from the Previous and Next nodes each time.

**Here is a sample of the XML structure:**

```
<comic>
      <id>117</id>
      <index>1</index>
      <mainsection>
        <pagecount>33</pagecount>
        <series>
          <displayname>Amazing Story</displayname>
          <sortname>Amazing Story</sortname>
        </series>
      </mainsection>
</comic>
<comic>
      <id>102</id>
      <index>1</index>
      <mainsection>
        <pagecount>33</pagecount>
        <series>
          <displayname>Fantastic Tale</displayname>
          <sortname>Fantastic Tale</sortname>
        </series>
      </mainsection>
</comic>
<comic>
      <id>85</id>
      <index>1</index>
      <mainsection>
        <pagecount>33</pagecount>
        <series>
          <displayname>The Great Tale</displayname>
          <sortname>The Great Tale</sortname>
        </series>
      </mainsection>
</comic>
```

**And here is a sample of the structure I am using in the loop:**

```
$prevIssue = $comic->xpath('preceding-sibling::*')->mainsection->series->displayname;
$nextIssue = $comic->xpath('following-sibling::*')->mainsection->series->displayname;

echo '
<li class="issue" id="' . $seriesCat . '">
<h3>' . $comicSeriresName . '</h3>
   <div id="details">
   <span id="publisher">' . $comicPublisher . '</span><br>
    The last series was called "' . $prevIssue . '<br>
    The next series is called "' . $nextIssue . '<br>
   </div>
</li>';
```

However, the 'nextIssue' and 'prevIssue' variables are not working. They are returning a blank result.  What am I doing wrong?

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code

```php
$prevIssue_arr = $comic->xpath('preceding-sibling::*[1]');
$prevIssue = (isset($prevIssue_arr[0])) ? $prevIssue_arr[0]->mainsection->series->displayname : '';
$nextIssue_arr = $comic->xpath('following-sibling::*[1]');
$nextIssue = (isset($nextIssue_arr[0])) ? $nextIssue_arr[0]->mainsection->series->displayname : '';

echo ...
```

[Edited]

The others have already explained why the code did not work

One is that the `xpath()` method returns an array of SimpleXMLElement objects. If no matching node is found, an empty array is returned.

The other is that without the predicate `[1]` or `[position()=1]` in the location path, all the preceding or succeeding `comic` nodes would be returned.

Alternatively you can use the location path `'following-sibling::comic[1]/mainsection/series'` to get just the required `series` node from the immediate succeeding sibling. If there were multiple `series` nodes, the position would have to be given or all of them would be returned.

So using this location path

```
$prevIssue_arr = $comic->xpath('preceding-sibling::comic[1]/mainsection/series');
$prevIssue = (isset($prevIssue_arr[0])) ? $prevIssue_arr[0]->displayname : '';
$nextIssue_arr = $comic->xpath('following-sibling::comic[1]/mainsection/series');
$nextIssue = (isset($nextIssue_arr[0])) ? $nextIssue_arr[0]->displayname : '';
```

Comment: This is probably the right answer, but it would be much more useful if you explained *why* this will fix it, so that the answer can be applied to more than just one situation.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
preceding-sibling::*
```

Selects *all* preceding sibling elements.

```
following-sibling::*
```

Selects *all* following sibling elements.

**You want just one -- the direct preceding sibling or the direct following sibling -- respectively**:

```
preceding-sibling::*[1]
```

**and**:

```
following-sibling::*[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem, as touched on by other answers but not explicitly explained, is that unlike most operations on SimpleXML objects, `->xpath()` returns an **array**, not another SimpleXML object. (This is presumably to avoid having a SimpleXML object that could contain completely unrelated nodes from throughout the document.)

Thus this line will fail, because you are treating an array as an object:

```
$prevIssue = $comic->xpath('preceding-sibling::*')->mainsection->series->displayname;
```

In PHP 5.4, the following is valid syntax (indexing into the array immediately after it is returned):

```
$prevIssue = $comic->xpath('preceding-sibling::*')[0]->mainsection->series->displayname;
```

But for earlier versions of PHP, or if the XPath might sometimes return 0 results, you need an intermediate variable:

```
$prevSiblings = $comic->xpath('preceding-sibling::*');
$prevIssue = (
    ( count($prevSiblings) > 0 )
    ? $prevSiblings[0]->mainsection->series->displayname
    : NULL
);
```